# I do not know where to start this challenge, help please

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive numbers such that $1\leq xy+yz+zx\leq3$ which is the set of values ​​of $xyz$? And $x + y + z$?$$$$Knowing that $x, y$ and $z$ $\in\mathbb{R^*}$

Comment: are they positive real numbers or positive integers

Comment: Clearly they cannot be integers (unless they are all $1$).

Comment: @Jam I would like to understand the two ways .... :)

Comment: if they are all integers answer is trivial x=y=z=1               but if they are all real numbers its a different game

Comment: It is true, then the same must be true ... Thank you ...

Comment: For the sum: Let $z=0, y = \frac{3}{x}$ and $N$ be an upper bound, then for $x=N$
$$x+y+z = N + \frac{3}{N} + 0 > N$$
So $x+y+z$ can become arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For the product use $$\sqrt[3]{(xyz)^2} \le \dfrac{xy+yz+zx}{3}$$ and $x\cdot 1\cdot 1 \to 0,\ x \to 0$.
For the sum use $$2(x+y+z)^2 = 2x^2+2y^2+2z^2 +4(xy+yz+zx) = x^2+y^2+x^2+z^2+y^2+z^2 +4(xy+yz+zx) \ge 6(xy+yz+zx)$$ and $x+\frac1x+\frac1x \to +\infty,\ x \to +\infty$.

> So $0 < xyz \le 1$ and $\sqrt{3} \le x+y+z<+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry friend, but did not understand almost nothing. Could more detail?

Comment: Which part(s) didn't you understand? In both cases I just used the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: I could not understand what and how to use this inequality.